# Create a layout to include with a recyclerview and pass tools:listItem as argument

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-databinding

I´m trying to create a include to use as a default recyclerview to reuse in all my views, the code is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

        <import type="android.view.View" />

        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.jsm.baserecycler.BaseRecyclerViewModel" />
        <variable
            name="listItemResource"
            type="android.widget.LinearLayout" />
    </data>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipeRefreshLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:onRefreshListener="@{() -> viewModel.onRefresh()}"
        app:refreshing="@{viewModel.isLoading}">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/elementsRV"
            style="@style/RecyclerView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:listitem="@{listItemResource}">

        </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
    </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/empty"
        style="@style/TextViewNoItems"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/default_recyclerview_emptyMessage"
        android:visibility="@{viewModel.textEmptyVisibility ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

My goal is to pass a variable to the include which can configure the tools:listItem of the recycler inside the include

I tried to find which type I need to put in listItemResource to use the variable in

```
tools:listitem
```

I tried several types as Integer, Viewgroup... but always receive a error of type:

```
{"msg":"Cannot find a setter for \u003candroidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView tools:listitem\u003e that accepts parameter type...
```

Which type I need to put on **????**....

```
<variable
            name="listItemResource"
            type="????" />
```

...To do:

```
 tools:listitem="@{listItemResource}
```

?

Update: As [ADM](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4168607/adm) pointed in comments and I researched, my approach is wrong, I guess the solution is to create a CompoundView that accepts that parameter

Comment: are you sure you want to use `tools:listitem` ? you know this will have no impact at runtime, right ?

Comment: Yes i know, it´s for design purposes

Comment: Data Binding binds the data at runtime . You can not pass `listItemResource` at compile time anyway so whats the point of doing this ? I never done that but i think variable Type should be `ViewGroup` u can go and create a BindingAdapter for this but i don't think you can set `tools` property with code and again it will not have any impact at compile time .

Comment: @ADM you are right, as I researched tools have no sense at binding time. I updated my question, and will provide a solution based on a compound view if it´s possible ASAP

Comment: @JoaquinSainzdelaMaza I think this is not possible